# Replication of UITableView structure within the same tableView.frame

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections. In my first section, there are 5 rows. In second section there are 2 rows. When I click on an add button,this table view has to be replicated again and again. How can I do that?

```
-(IBAction)addDetails:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"value of s is %d,%d",s,210+100*s);

    tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tvc.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(20,200+250*s,280,280);
    //CGRect rect = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x+10, cell.bounds.origin.y+10,50,30);   
    [tvc.tableView setSectionFooterHeight:3.0];
    [tvc.tableView setSectionHeaderHeight:3.0];

    [tvc.tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
    // [tvc.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor  colorWithRed:67.0/255.0 green:185.0/255.0 blue:209.0/255.0 alpha:0.5]];
    [tvc.tableView setRowHeight:30];
    tvc.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    tvc.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tvc.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
    tvc.tableView.delegate = self;
    tvc.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tvc.tableView];
   s++;

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

      if(section == DETAIL_SECTION)
          return 5;
      else if(section == CALENDER_SECTION){
          return 2;
      }


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

When the addDetails Function is invoked again,I want the same table structure with different data in it within the same frame.Now frame is getting repeated.
Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Define "replicated". You want an identical `UITableView` to be created?

Comment: Define your question properly. Then i can answer in better way. Describe more.

Comment: please put ur code here >>:_) for more understanding

Comment: @Adam Wright,Nirav,iPatel:Replicated means, I want the same table structure again and again with different data in it

Comment: can you put the data source array? or how do you fill the cells? any way their is no need to re-initiate the table on every button click, you can just modify the the array (od any other source) that contains the data

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the add button, create a new `UITableView` instance, add it to an existing view as a subview.  Position and size it according to your needs.  Set its delegate and datasource to be the same delegate and datasource as the original. This way, the same delegate/datasource methods will act on each of the tables using the same logic.  Whenever you reload the original table, be sure to reload all 'replicated' tables.